# Variable returned by Reference from a function gives weird values

Tags: c, function, reference, return

I've been working on a hangman game lately, and this function supposedly checks for a letter that the user inputs in an array (Containing a pre-defined word such as "BUILDING") and adds on a Counter (Count) if the letter exists or decreases the lives (Which start at 5 -defined in the main function-) if it doesn't exist.

Now the Count variable works fine but the Lives variable keeps decreasing anyways, even if the letter exists and it doesn't just decrease by 1 but by bigger amounts resulting in rather big negative numbers.

Here's the code, thanks in advance:

```
void Checkf(char X,int r,int Length,char *Hidden, int *Lives,int *Count)
{
int i;
for (i=0;i<Length;i++)
{
    if (X==Words[r][i] && Hidden[i]=='*')
    {
        Hidden[i] = X;
        *Count = *Count + 1;
    }
    else if (X!=Words[r][i] && Hidden[i]=='*')
    *Lives = *Lives - 1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior occurs because you (optionally) decrease the value of `Lives` on each iteration of the loop.
You can add a variable that indicates whether the letter was found or not, and then decrease the value of Lives after the loop ends, like this:

```
void Checkf(char X,int r,int Length,char *Hidden, int *Lives,int *Count)
{
int i;
unsigned char found = 0;
for (i=0;i<Length;i++)
{
    if (X==Words[r][i] && Hidden[i]=='*')
    {
        Hidden[i] = X;
        *Count = *Count + 1;
        found = 1;
    }
}
if (!found)
{
    *Lives -= 1;
}
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the fast response. I'm still kind of new to this you see. I tried your method and it ended up decreasing by 1 every time I enter a letter, so it's working better now but still decreases even if the letter is found, here's the code:

Comment: `void Checkf(char X,int r,int Length,char *Hidden, int *Lives,int *Count)
{
    int i;
    int Found = 0;
    for (i=0;i<Length;i++)
    {
        if (X==Words[r][i] && Hidden[i]=='*')
        {
            Hidden[i] = X;
            *Count = *Count + 1;
            Found = 1;
        }
    }
    if (!Found)
    {
        *Lives = *Lives - 1;
    }}`

Comment: If it gets decreased every time, it means that the letter wasn't really found (previously you said that `Count` works fine, so if `Count` is still increased, `Found` should be set and the `Lives` shouldn't be decreased). Can I see the code which calls that function?

Comment: I have 2 assumptions as to what may be the cause of your problem:
1. You use getchar() and call that function inside a loop, so it actually gets called twice: once with the input letter and then another time with '\n'.
2. `Hidden` is how the user sees the word, and when the user uses the same input twice, the second time won't count as "found" because the letter is not "hidden" anymore, so that block won't be reached and the user's Lives will decrease.

Comment: That second assumption makes a lot of sense I suppose but I believe I handled that in the code, I'll link you to the code anyways. I'm really sorry for all the hassle! Thanks alot ^^ https://www.dropbox.com/s/vc0adcuuy3gbi10/main.c?dl=0